# Deadlock with one thread Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, boost-asio

I'am currently struggeling with an deadlock issue, but can't figure out if it's a wrong useage of Boost:Asio, or anything else...

The biggest issue is i can't reproduce it since it does not happen every time, it's more like "once in a lifetime", so it must be some kind of raise condition. The whole gdb backtrace is this:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (process 23619):
#0  0x00007f66a24ea42d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f66a24e5dcb in _L_lock_812 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f66a24e5c98 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x0000000000426968 in pthread_mutex_lock (m=0xb77288) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:62
#4  lock (this=0xb77288) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:116
#5  lock (this=0xb77288) at /usr/include/boost/thread/lockable_adapter.hpp:42
#6  lock_guard (m_=..., this=<synthetic pointer>) at /usr/include/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:38
#7  EndpointGroup::addEndpoint (this=0xb77288, endpoint=std::shared_ptr (count 1, weak 1) 0xbe4528) at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/EndpointGroup.cpp:80
#8  0x0000000000429b29 in EndpointManager::getQueuedOrNewEndpoint (this=this@entry=0x6abd60 <EndpointManager::getInstance()::instance>)
    at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/EndpointManager.cpp:54
#9  0x000000000042a620 in EndpointManager::fetchEndpoint (this=0x6abd60 <EndpointManager::getInstance()::instance>, endpointAddress="185.150.4.67")
    at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/EndpointManager.cpp:67
#10 0x000000000041404b in Client::processAlloc (this=this@entry=0xb76bb8, message=message@entry=0xbba290, response=response@entry=0xb8af60)
    at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/Client.cpp:279
#11 0x000000000041546e in Client::receiveMessage (this=0xb76bb8, message=0xbba290, response=response@entry=0xb8af60) at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/Client.cpp:46
#12 0x00000000004178e6 in operator() (__closure=<optimized out>, receivedBytes=<optimized out>, ec=...) at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/ClientConnection.cpp:119
#13 operator() (this=0x7ffc352d6da0) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:127
#14 asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<ClientConnection::doRead()::__lambda0, boost::system::error_code, long unsigned int> > (function=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:69
#15 invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<ClientConnection::doRead()::__lambda0, boost::system::error_code, long unsigned int>, ClientConnection::doRead()::__lambda0> (
    context=..., function=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:37
#16 boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, ClientConnection::doRead()::__lambda0>::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::io_service_impl *, boost::asio::detail::operation *, const boost::system::error_code &, std::size_t) (owner=<optimized out>, base=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp:110
#17 0x000000000042f7d0 in complete (bytes_transferred=<optimized out>, ec=..., owner=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
#18 do_run_one (ec=..., this_thread=..., lock=..., this=0xb43b50) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:372
#19 boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run (this=0xb43b50, ec=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:149
#20 0x000000000042cc85 in run (this=0xb43ad0) at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
#21 MediaControl::run (this=this@entry=0xb43ad0) at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/MediaControl.cpp:82
#22 0x0000000000410f6f in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at /tmp/mediacontrol/src/main.cpp:106
```

The program (simplified):

1. Receive Alloc message
2. Create and run an asio::io_service
3. Pass the asio::io_service to a "EndpointGroup" to use it with a asio::high_resolution_timer
4. Starting the timer
5. Add an item to a list used in the function after the timer expired (MUTEX) <- here blocks it
6. Timer expires and uses the list (MUTEX)

I have also to note in the "EndpointGroup" these two lock_guards are the only ones in this class. The functions seem to be different but the "RtpEndpoint" does not start the "EndpointGroup" anymore it will be started on creating.
The related functions:

```
// create a service which is used for async operations
io_service_ptr ThreadPoolManager::createNewService()
{
    io_service_ptr io_service = std::make_shared<asio::io_service>();
    work_ptr work = std::make_shared<asio::io_service::work>(*io_service);
    io_services_endpoint.push_back(io_service);
    work_endpoint.push_back(work);
    threads_endpoint.create_thread(bind(&asio::io_service::run, io_service));
    return io_service;
}

// simply start this function over and over again every 10ms
void EndpointGroup::invokeSendingOnEndpoints(size_t offset)
{
    pTimer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(PTIME_INTERVAL - offset));
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    pTimer.async_wait([this, self](system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            vector<rtp_endpoint_ptr> iterationEndpoints;
            {
                boost::lock_guard<EndpointGroup> guard(*this);
                iterationEndpoints = endpoints;
            }
            for (rtp_endpoint_ptr endpoint : iterationEndpoints)
            {
                // do fancy stuff
            }
            ++pTimerIterations;
            // check how many milliseconds passed since start of the function
            invokeSendingOnEndpoints(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>((std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start)).count() / (pTimerIterations * PTIME_INTERVAL));
        }
        else
        {
            // just write error happend....    
        }
    });
}

bool EndpointGroup::addEndpoint(const rtp_endpoint_ptr& endpoint)
{
    boost::lock_guard<EndpointGroup> guard(*this);
    endpoints.push_back(endpoint);
    return true;
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions how to debug this and hopefully solve this issue.

**Update 1**

Since some asked for more information etc. here they come.
The goal of the program, think of FreeSwitch/Asterisk, but smaller. It's still propably a naive approach. This program is a server which receives a request to allocate a new RTP-Endpoint since there can be hundreds of them this should be multithreaded (multiple io_services thats what i understood). And since using one thread per Endpoint is bad they are going to be grouped within the EndpointGroup. So the timer used is going to invoke the RTP-Endpoint every 10ms to start encoding and sending RTP.

I also reconsidered your suggestions to use a mutex member variable instead of inheriting from basic_lockable_adapter. The Answer by @sehe is pretty much the same i'am using, except for a client (different io_service/thread) which adds the Endpoints.

Comment: If you have multiple mutexes - always lock them in the same order.

Comment: @UKMonkey i don't have multiple mutexes, just one for the "EndpointGroup" which is used only at these two functions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are you, perhaps, trying to get the result of a future you haven't processed? If you do and there's no thread to process it, you'll get a deadlock.

Comment: `boost::lock_guard<EndpointGroup> guard(*this);` wait - did you make your endpoint group a mutex?  So that any object outside could lock it?  Don't do that... it's one of the first rules of java (because everything can be locked) never lock on this because anything else could... lock on a member.

Comment: why on earth are you dynamically creating io_services? one is usually enough for an entire program.

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks for pointing this out. But i did not inherit from a mutex, but from basic_lockable_adapter, which also exposes lock() and unlock()

Comment: @RichardHodges I need multiple threads, have a look at the added infos

Comment: @Hestalon asio supports the idea of one io_service being serviced by multiple threads. It also has inbuilt supports for mutual exclusion (see asio::io_service::strand)

Comment: @RichardHodges propably i stil have to learn more from asio. But till now i wasn't able to multithread it without multiple io_services, since the program only waits for async operations on udp-sockets.

Comment: @Hestalon suggest you look at the example applications embedded in the boost documentation. It's covered there.

Answer (score 1):

I spent around 20 minutes to make your sample code into something self-contained. Of course, it just works, but that's because you're not showing the code that locks, anyways.

Perhaps the way I extrapolated and in filled-in-the-blanks will help you spot what you do differently:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d347580676aee673)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

static const auto PTIME_INTERVAL = 10;
static std::atomic_size_t pTimerIterations { 0 };

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using io_service_ptr = std::shared_ptr<asio::io_service>;
using work_ptr = std::shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work>;

struct ThreadPoolManager {
    std::vector<io_service_ptr> io_services_endpoint;
    std::vector<work_ptr> work_endpoint;
    boost::thread_group threads_endpoint;

    io_service_ptr createNewService() {
        io_service_ptr io_service = std::make_shared<asio::io_service>();
        work_ptr work = std::make_shared<asio::io_service::work>(*io_service);
        io_services_endpoint.push_back(io_service);
        work_endpoint.push_back(work);
        threads_endpoint.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, io_service));

        return io_service;
    }

    ~ThreadPoolManager() {
        for(auto& w : work_endpoint)
            w.reset();

        threads_endpoint.join_all();
    }
};

struct RtpEndpoint {
};

using rtp_endpoint_ptr = std::shared_ptr<RtpEndpoint>;

struct EndpointGroup : std::enable_shared_from_this<EndpointGroup>, boost::mutex {
    io_service_ptr _io;
    asio::high_resolution_timer pTimer;
    std::vector<rtp_endpoint_ptr> endpoints;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    EndpointGroup(io_service_ptr io) : _io(io), pTimer(*_io) {}

    void stop() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        _io->post([self,this] { pTimer.cancel(); });
    }

    // simply start this function over and over again every 10ms
    void invokeSendingOnEndpoints(size_t offset) {
        pTimer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(PTIME_INTERVAL - offset));

        auto self(shared_from_this());
        pTimer.async_wait([this, self](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::vector<rtp_endpoint_ptr> iterationEndpoints;
                {
                    boost::lock_guard<EndpointGroup> guard(*this);
                    iterationEndpoints = endpoints;
                }
                for (rtp_endpoint_ptr endpoint : iterationEndpoints) {
                    // do fancy stuff
                }
                ++pTimerIterations;
                // check how many milliseconds passed since start of the function
                invokeSendingOnEndpoints(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                                             (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start))
                                             .count() /
                                         (pTimerIterations * PTIME_INTERVAL));
            } else {
                // just write error happend....
            }
        });
    }

    bool addEndpoint(const rtp_endpoint_ptr &endpoint) {
        boost::lock_guard<EndpointGroup> guard(*this);
        endpoints.push_back(endpoint);
        return true;
    }
};

using group_ptr = std::shared_ptr<EndpointGroup>;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "starting" << std::endl;
    {
        ThreadPoolManager tpm;

        std::vector<group_ptr> groups;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Group " << i << std::endl;
            auto epg = std::make_shared<EndpointGroup>(tpm.createNewService());
            epg->invokeSendingOnEndpoints(i*2);

            for (int j = 0; j < rand()%10; ++j) {
                epg->addEndpoint(std::make_shared<RtpEndpoint>());
                std::cout << " - RtpEndpoint " << i << "." << j << std::endl;
            }

            groups.push_back(epg);
        }

        std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        std::cout << "shutting down" << std::endl;

        for(auto& g : groups)
            g->stop();
    }
    std::cout << "done, " << pTimerIterations << " iterations" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
starting
Group 0
 - RtpEndpoint 0.0
 - RtpEndpoint 0.1
 - RtpEndpoint 0.2
 - RtpEndpoint 0.3
Group 1
 - RtpEndpoint 1.0
 - RtpEndpoint 1.1
Group 2
 - RtpEndpoint 2.0
Group 3
 - RtpEndpoint 3.0
 - RtpEndpoint 3.1
Group 4
 - RtpEndpoint 4.0
 - RtpEndpoint 4.1
 - RtpEndpoint 4.2
waiting...
shutting down
done, 1963 iterations
```

### However

Like others have mentioned, this is highly unorthodox code.

1. You could simply have the same with only 1 `io_service`
2. having parallel containers is a code smell (have one vector of `struct { thread, service, work }` instead of three containing services, threads and work objects.
3. never inherit from `std::mutex`. There's also precious little reason to implement a [BasicLockable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable) yourself. Instead, expose a `unique_lock` if you must. It'll be exception safe and have well defined defer/adopt semantics.
4. the timing business looks a lot like you're trying to achieve what I demonstrated in this answer: [boost::asio::deadline_timer 1ms lags after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769347/boostasiodeadline-timer-1ms-lags-after-some-time/49773792#49773792)

In this case I'd reckon you need at most 1 io_service + 1 work object for the whole pool, here's a simplified take:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d22935e137a49c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

static const auto PTIME_INTERVAL = 10; // boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10);
static std::atomic_size_t pTimerIterations { 0 };

namespace asio = boost::asio;

struct ThreadPoolManager {
    ~ThreadPoolManager() {
        work.reset();
        threads_endpoint.join_all();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& get_service() { return io; }

    void launch() {
        threads_endpoint.create_thread([this]{ io.run(); });
    }

  private:
    asio::io_service io;
    boost::optional<asio::io_service::work> work {io};
    boost::thread_group threads_endpoint;
};

struct RtpEndpoint {
};

using rtp_endpoint_ptr = std::shared_ptr<RtpEndpoint>;

struct EndpointGroup : std::enable_shared_from_this<EndpointGroup> {
    std::mutex _mx;
    asio::io_service& _io;
    asio::high_resolution_timer pTimer;
    std::vector<rtp_endpoint_ptr> endpoints;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    EndpointGroup(asio::io_service& io) : _io(io), pTimer(_io) {}

    void stop() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        _io.post([self,this] { pTimer.cancel(); });
    }

    // simply start this function over and over again every 10ms
    void invokeSendingOnEndpoints(size_t offset) {
        pTimer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(PTIME_INTERVAL - offset));

        auto self(shared_from_this());
        pTimer.async_wait([this, self](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::vector<rtp_endpoint_ptr> iterationEndpoints;
                {
                    boost::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mx);
                    iterationEndpoints = endpoints;
                }
                for (rtp_endpoint_ptr endpoint : iterationEndpoints) {
                    // do fancy stuff
                }
                ++pTimerIterations;
                // check how many milliseconds passed since start of the function
                invokeSendingOnEndpoints(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                                             (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start))
                                             .count() /
                                         (pTimerIterations * PTIME_INTERVAL));
            } else {
                // just write error happend....
            }
        });
    }

    bool addEndpoint(const rtp_endpoint_ptr &endpoint) {
        boost::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mx);
        endpoints.push_back(endpoint);
        return true;
    }
};

using group_ptr = std::shared_ptr<EndpointGroup>;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "starting" << std::endl;
    {
        ThreadPoolManager tpm;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
            tpm.launch();

        std::vector<group_ptr> groups;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Group " << i << std::endl;
            auto epg = std::make_shared<EndpointGroup>(tpm.get_service());
            epg->invokeSendingOnEndpoints(i*2);

            for (int j = 0; j < rand()%10; ++j) {
                epg->addEndpoint(std::make_shared<RtpEndpoint>());
                std::cout << " - RtpEndpoint " << i << "." << j << std::endl;
            }

            groups.push_back(epg);
        }

        std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        std::cout << "shutting down" << std::endl;

        for(auto& g : groups)
            g->stop();
    }
    std::cout << "done, " << pTimerIterations << " iterations" << std::endl;
}
```

Having the same output.

Comment: I updated the original Question for some more info.
And yes your considerations are also correct (see also the udpates above). But only one io_service will never fit the requirements the whole program has. I wished to could have combined them like you suggest, but i had to (was not my decision). The mutex stuff i changed like everyone suggested, using a member variable, before inherit from basic_lockable_adapter. And your other answer is not like what i have here. But still thanks a lot.